# How to show alert after keyboard has been shown in UITextView textViewDidBeginEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uialertcontroller

Inside textViewDidBeginEditing I'm showing alert using UIAlertController. Alert is shown prior to the keyboard (on simulator).
How do I show keyboard before alert pops up?

```
 func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    if self.balance <= 0 {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Balance Low", message: "Your balance is low.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) { (cancel) in
        }

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Buy", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in
            self.segueToBuy()
        }

        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: Use `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)` instead.

Comment: When would you like to show the alert ? While user begins to start typing the text Or When controller loads up or some event occurs ?

Comment: When user enter the textView to type I check for low balance, that's the point when I want to show Alert if balance is low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` to show the alert after certain delay, whenever user typed the text in `UITextView`.

```
func asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime, qos: DispatchQoS = default, flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags = default, execute work: @escaping @convention(block) () -> Void)
```

Delcare private instance variable which is used to show alert, locally.

```
var showAlert = true
```

Try the code shown below in `textViewDidBeginEditing`:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    if self.showAlert && self.balance <= 0 {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            textView.endEditing(true)
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Balance Low", message: "Your balance is low.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel) { (cancel) in

                self.showAlert = false
                textView.becomeFirstResponder()
            }

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Buy", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (action) in

                textView.endEditing(true)
                self.segueToBuy()
            }

            alert.addAction(cancelAction)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if I missed any scenario or your requirement is different than I understand.

Comment: Tx, seems to solve my issue. One question, why did you add textView.endEditing(true) in the code before we take any action on alert? This will not allow user to type if he has sufficient balance? Or does it serve any other purpose?

Comment: You are welcome. If we didn't write textView.endEditing(true) before showing alert, then textViewDidBeginEditing(:_) gets called again after user dismissed the alert. Again, alert will be shown, user will be hiding the alert, it is happening repeatedly. That's why. Let me edit my answer to suit for your scenario.

Comment: Tx Sateesh, it now clarifies.